# How many solutions to the equation $C \equiv M^e \;(\mbox{mod}\;n)$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Fix $n,e\in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $C\in\mathbb{Z}_n$.
How many solutions $M\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ do I have to the equation $$C \equiv M^e \;(\mbox{mod}\;n)\;?$$
This question arose from trying to solve the equation 
$$11\equiv M^7\;(\mbox{mod}\;187),$$
for $M<187. $

Comment: RSA algorithm ?

Comment: Yes I was reading into RSA and out of curiosity I asked myself the quesion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=Z_n$, $M \in G$ and $r = Ord_G(M)$. There are $r$ unique residues thus $r$ possible exponents $e$ for selected $M$. Note that $r \mid \lambda(n)$ where $\lambda(n)$ is the Charmichael lambda function on $n$. When $n\ \in \mathbb{P}$ (prime) then $\lambda(n) = \varphi(n)$ as it's a cyclic group generated by $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ generatos.

Comment: But the OP doesn't assume $M$ is coprime to $n$ so $M$ may have no order.

Comment: Well, indeed you are right! When $M$ is a non-unit, this is $\gcd(M,n)\neq 1$ there's no multiplicative order. Moreover, the product of non-units it's a non-unit again. But in RSA, taking any non-unit $M$ would reveal a non-trivial factor of the modulus, this is a very important fact as $\gcd(M,n)=p$ or $q$.